# Spring webapp security based on owner of record

Tags: spring-security

Let's say I have users and articles.

Anonymous can list and read articles.
Only registered and logged user can create articles.
User can edit only own articles.
And, of course, admin can do anything.

I've looked at spring security, but didn't found a way to do that. My app don't need roles, and ACL will be too "heavy" for that.

Maybe I should implement my own security?

Comment: What do you mean "my app don't need roles"?  You just *described* the roles yourself.

Comment: I need only anonymous and logged user. For admin I can do another site area

Comment: Fine, but those are still roles.

Comment: What do you need security for ? If both anonymous and logged in users can access the same URLs then yes maybe you don't need spring-security or any security. Is this the case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, ACL would be too much for the task.

You can use Spring Security's authorize tag in JSP, which provides access to the logged in user via the `principal` object. Example to limit access to editing an article to the user with a given username:

```
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('SOME_PRIVILEGE_OR_ROLE') and ${someArticle.username} == principal.username">
    ...
</sec:authorize>
```

Note that SOME_PRIVILEGE_OR_ROLE could be some role like 'LOGGED_IN_USER', but could also rather specify a certain privilege, e.g. 'READ_ARTICLE' or 'UPDATE_ARTICLE'. Spring Security is flexible here. Whatever you choose, it needs to be in the GrantedAuthorities collection of your user object.

Note also that you can implement your own user object, adding further info to what the UserDetails interface provides, e.g. comparing the user's id rather than the username.

Finally, note that you need a recent version of Spring Security (>=3.1) for the Spring EL to work as in the example.

Comment: Thank, that works. For those, who prefer programmatic way(as me). You can annotate controller method with @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER') and #someArticle.creatorId == principal.id") where #someArticle is method parameter